# Function to find the duplicate characters in a string with their number of occurrences in the Dart language

Tags: dart

How can we find duplicate characters in a string with their number of occurrences? The function should be generic in the Dart language.

Sample:

Input = “abcBCAacd”

Output = “a”: 3 
“B” : 2 , “c” :3

Comment: Does not seem you learn anything from your last question (which was closed because you do not provide any code). Please provide your own code and explain what your problem is. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service where you can just get other people solve your assignments.

Comment: I would urge you to look at the following resource and try it on your own. If you have errors and still need help, you must update the question first by adding the code that you have used.

Link: https://medium.com/flutter-community/exploring-string-methods-in-dart-324f747b8d15

Comment: The question is not well-defined without defining "characters". If you just consider any code unit in the string as a character, it's fairly simple. If not, it's exceedingly complicated. Does `"áá"` contain a duplicate (it's a single `á` code unit followed by an `a` and a combining accent). If the question is restricted to ASCII only, it should be simple, but also not particularly useful in practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  var input = 'abcBCAacd'.toLowerCase().split('');
  var list1 = input.toSet();
  var myMap = Map<String, int>.fromIterables(list1, List.generate(list1.length, (i) => 0));
  input.forEach((e) => myMap[e] = myMap[e]! + 1);
  print(myMap);
}
```

Result:

```
{a: 3, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1}
```

Comment: This seems far more complex than necessary.  See mine.

Comment: It seems, nothing more. The fourth line (initialization for Map) can be suppressed and a tiny change into fifth line and that's all folks....

Answer (score 1):

I had to presume you wanted the `d` counted, and that everything should be folded to lowercase.  If `B` and `b` are in different buckets, just remove the `toLowerCase()` from below:

```
void main() {
  var input = 'abcBCAacd';
  var chars = input.toLowerCase().split('');
  var counts = <String, int>{};
  for (var char in chars) {
    counts[char] = (counts[char] ?? 0) + 1;
  }
  print(counts);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the `update` method on map which provides a `ifAbsent` argument: `counts.update(char, (count) => count + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1);`.

Comment: ahh, I was looking for that.  Mine is shorter though. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  
  int nbOccurence = 0;
  String input ="abcdeffff";
   for( var i = 0 ; i < input.length; i++ ) { 
     nbOccurence = 0;
      for( var j = 0 ; j < input.length; j++ ) {
        if (input[i] == input[j]){
          nbOccurence++;
        }
      }
     print(input[i] + ":" + nbOccurence.toString());
   }
  
}
```

Comment: This has O(n^2) efficiciency.  See the other solutions.